# Magento critical security patches - How to apply

Tags: magento

Today when i logged into my magento store admin,  it shown a new critical message like 
**Critical Reminder: Download and install Magento security patches. Download now.**
Then i download SUPEE-5344 and SUPEE-1533 from **https://www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/magento**.

Please tell me how can i apply these patch files to my magento store.

Thank You!

Comment: Run patch on windows please see this answer http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/64241

Comment: You can use SecureShell which is a Google Chrome App. I have used this for quite some time now and works very effectively.

Answer (score 2):

Applying SUPEE-5344 and SUPEE-1533 Magento patches via FTP/sFTP or FileManager / File Upload without SSH

Refer Link: http://magentary.com/kb/apply-supee-5344-and-supee-1533-without-ssh/

You can test whether Magento is safe from vulnerable for security point of view see link: https://shoplift.byte.nl/ and enter your URL.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the official documentation on [applying patches](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/other/ht_install-patches.html)

But in short.

- Download the patch from the Magento site,
- Transfer the patch to you Magento installation root directory,
- Call `sh patch-file-name.sh` and you should see the message `Patch was applied/reverted successfully.`,

You may need to revert permissions after the process and also make sure you download the right patch for the version of Magento you have in place.

Comment: Please tell me how to call these command.. i have ssh enabled in my hosting.

Comment: @PHPCoder - use the `cd` command to navigate to your Magento root directory, then when you are there, type in at the command prompt `sh` and then the patch file name, hit enter. Case matters!

Comment: Please add this link to answer - http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/63858/critical-reminder-download-and-install-magento-security-patches-ftp-with-no-s

Answer (score 1):

for SSL use putty client software and use it to access SSL.
Go to your website hosted directory and type the
above command and yout patch get applied/reverted successfully.

Answer (score 0):

```
Steps To Run Security Patche File in magento.
  1 First download security error patche file from magento community .
  2 Download files move it into root folder in magento.
  3 Create a php file in root directory of magento for run patche  files.
  4 Rename Security patches files according to you.

Final Step Open Php file and add these function in php
<?php
print("<PRE>");
passthru("bash patch-1.sh");
print("</PRE>");
//patch-1.sh define the name of download security patch file name .
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First download .sh patch files and move to your document root (magento root folder). Then connect to ssh and go to your document root folder.
run this command.

```
sh patch-file-name.sh
```

A message such as the following displays to confirm the patch installed successfully:

```
Patch was applied/reverted successfully.
```

Delete cache and session.

```
rm -rf var/cache var/session
```

Now you may need to reassign ownership again. Based on your group name command. Generally there are two groups www-data or apache. If you have www-data then run this command

```
chown -R www-data .
```

For apache use this.

```
chown -R apache
```